# AppStore release of iOS app and its multiple Testflight builds on the same device

Tags: ios, testflight

I wonder if there is a practice of doing some tweaks on a configuration of development Testflight builds of iOS apps that makes possible having all the builds (including main current App's build obtained from AppStore) live on the same device.

For example, what config parameters should I operate on to have: MyApp (AppStore build), MyApp_TF_234, MyApp_TF_237, ... builds live on my device without any conflicts:

- No need to remove AppStore version of my app to see any TF build (that is why different names `TF_` convention)
- MyApp should still be treated as one and the same app by TF.

[This presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=SPb0IAmt7-GS1yeaObTQhq9onV_HfAwUj6&feature=player_detailpage&v=OJ94KqmsxiI#t=1586) describes something very similar to what I am asking here about, the difference is that I want to achieve this "multiple builds on the same device" with minimum steps to have it working with TF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible but you have to create the different bundle ID for every running application!

Comment: Yes, before you answered I tried it myself: I've changed bundle ID to be something like: com.mycompany.myapp.234 and CFBundleDisplayName to be like: MyApp (234) and it worked. The only problem I can see is that the TF list of apps will eventually become overwhelmed by the names of numerous numbered builds (one build == one app).

Comment: Yes, thats an issue, If I need to test numerous version I just increase the build number of app with same bundle id and i make pile of 100 apps, easily identified and manage

Comment: Also, now I see that a simplified setup can include just two bundle identifiers: com.company.myapp and com.company.myapp.testflight, where the former is designated for AppStore and the latter is used for all testflight builds.

Answer (score 3):

Just a couple of details in addition to the answer I've accepted as correct.

A simplified setup can include just two different bundle identifiers: com.company.myapp and com.company.MyApp.Testflight, where the former is designated for AppStore and the latter is used for all testflight builds. Now the Home screen of my device has two different apps: My App and My App (236).

Also, notice that Testflight generates new API token for each App created, so don't forget to set correct app token when you switch your app to be built for Testflight or switch it to be built for AppStore.

Very helfpul blog posts:[iOS multi-environment configuration](http://appfoundry.be/blog/2014/07/04/Xcode-Env-Configuration/), [iOS Quick Tip: Managing Configurations With Ease](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-managing-configurations-with-ease--mobile-18324).